# mediaelement.js video in IE 9 not working in Standards Mode

Tags: mediaelement.js

I've seen a couple of questions about MediaElement.js video appearing black in IE 9 but audio still playing. No one seems to have an answer though. I'm starting a new thread with additional information that I've observed.

I have one coworker who experiences this on her PC, but I can't replicate it on other machines. Another coworker says it happens on her home PC. I have not had a chance to compare exact IE build numbers between machines where it does work.

The problem is apparent on video hosted from our site and on http://mediaelementjs.com/

The video from our site and http://mediaelementjs.com/ is being served with a MIME type of video/mp4, which is correct, and the browser is seeing the MIME type.

The player is falling back on Flash to play the MP4.

If, however, I play a video hosted on YouTube in our player, it works properly.

The video being sent from YouTube is being served with a MIME type of video/x-flv.

If I use IE's Web Developer to switch the document mode to Quirks, IE 7, or IE 8, the video displays normally.

I don't know if it matters, but I recently switched from wmode=opaque to wmode=transparent on the Flash fallback. I can try testing that, but since it involves redeploying code to the main site and there are good reasons I made that switch, I'm holding off on switching it live unless I have to.

Anyone see anything in here that might be a clue?

Comment: Just an update that this hasn't been resolved, but I also haven't encountered any other instances of this problem besides the ones I mentioned above.